# TextInputLayout with AutoCompleteTextView using ArrayAdapter set Selected Item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I have a TextInputLayout with AutoCompleteTextView as a 'Spinner'. I populate the AutoCompleteTextView with an ArrayAdapter like this:

```
val adapter: ArrayAdapter<Currency> = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.item_til_dropdown, currencies)
binding.currency.setAdapter(adapter)
```

This is my XML for the TextInputLayout with the AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/currency_til"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textinputlayout_margin"
                android:hint="Currency"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/currency"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:inputType="none" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I'm struggling to set the selected item. I have tried:

```
binding.currency.setText(currency.toString())
```

But this removes the other items in the list and puts the current one in it alone.

So my question is how do I set the Selected Item without it removing the other items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by first setting the text of the AutoCompleteTextView then after that populating the ArrayAdapter.